# How can i get a specific version from the TFS using Web Matrix?

Tags: tfs, webmatrix, webmatrix-2, webmatrix-3

I would like to get a specific version from the TFS using Web Matrix. Where can I use the following features in Web Matrix?

1. Compare
2. View History
3. Get Specific Version
   [image]

I am able to see those feature in Visual Studio IDE but not in Web Matrix.
[image]

Please help me someone regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

WebMatrix is a lightweight development environment.  TFS is not supported and since that's more of a heavy weight technology, I can't imagine it will ever be supported.

Comment: WebMatrix integrates with both TFS and GIT. The integration is, however, quite poor and buggy IMO and is not likely to be fixed.